# Android application write to sdcard files

Tags: android, filewriter

I have written the following code to write to a file on external storage:

```
    public static BufferedWriter out;
    private void createFileOnDevice(Boolean append) throws IOException {
            File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.d("File",Root.toString());
            Root.setWritable(true);
            Root.setReadable(true);
            Log.d("File","Writable: " + Root.canWrite());
            if(Root.canWrite()){
                 File  LogFile = new File(Root, "/Android/DriverInterfaceSystem");
                 if(!LogFile.mkdirs()){
                     Log.d("File","Couldn't make directories");
                 }
                 LogFile = new File(LogFile, "/trace.txt");

                 Log.d("File",LogFile.toString());
                 try{
                     FileWriter LogWriter = new FileWriter(LogFile, true);
                     LogWriter.write("--- New Record ---");
                     out = new BufferedWriter(LogWriter);
                 } catch(IOException e){
                     Log.d("File","FileWriter failed");
                 }

                 out.write("New record");

            }
    }
```

I have set permissions in Manifest to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I know that having both a FileWriter and BufferedWriter is redundant, but I was testing if it was just one of them that wouldn't work.

When I run, the file is created in the correct location, but the program refuses to write either "-- New Record --" or "New Record" to the file, the file is just empty.

Given that the file is created, it seems that I'm missing one really simple step, but I'm damned if I can see it. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Root` should be spelled `root`... in Java, it is standard practice to have class names start with a capital letter and instance variables start with a lowercase letter. Just thought I'd mention that :).

Comment: Try using `out.flush()` and `out.close()`

Comment: Alex, you're right, it is better practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call flush() for it to actually write to the file. I think just calling write(...) only adds it to the buffer to be written. Here a quick example of usage:

```
FileWriter fWriter;
try{
    fWriter = new FileWriter(“\sdcard\filename.txt”);
    fWriter.write(yourString);
    fWriter.flush();
    fWriter.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i actually realised this myself about 30 seconds after asking the question. well done to everyone who was so quick in responding though :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `flush()` and `close()` on your `FileWriter`.

---

### Edit #1:

I'd also like to point out that the following code is unnecessary:

```
root.setWritable(true);
root.setReadable(true);
```

The call to `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a readable/writable `File` by default (assuming you've given your application the proper permissions).

---

### Edit #2:

Last thing. Please make sure that before you do any work with the external storage, you always call `getExternalStorageState()` to check whether the media is available. The media might be mounted to a computer, missing, read-only, or in some other state. See the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) for more information.